# Help: Quantile tables and confidence intervals

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, confidence-interval, chi-squared-test, quantiles

**Information about the data**

For this study, I would like to statistically test how the total length of sparrows affects their survival. Consider here one of the characteristics of the sparrows recorded was total length, which is assumed to be normally distributed.

Information regarding the data:

1. In a group of **21** surviving sparrows, the **variance** of the total length was **11.05 mm2**.
2. In a group of **28** sparrows that subsequently died, the **variance** of the total length was **15.07 mm2**.
3. The **µ** of the total length of sparrows that survived was **157.4 mm2**
4. The mean **µ** of the total length of sparrows that subsequently died was **158.4 mm2**

**Problems to solve:**

I am unsure if I have understood the concepts correctly underpinning how to: -

1. Read quantile tables properly for Chi-square and F distributions
2. Calculate 95 % confidence intervals

If this is possible, I would be incredibly grateful if anyone could please check the answers to the questions stated below by providing advice. Many thanks in advance for your help.

**Quantile Table**

[image]

**Question 1**

I would like to establish if the variance of the length of survivors is compatible with the calculated confidence interval for non-survivors?

Sample unit = total length of sparrows

- Calculate the 95 % CI for the variance of **15.07 mm2** for total length of 28 sparrows that did not survive

0.975 and 0.025 Chi-Square (χ2) distribution for non-survivors (n=28) inferred from the quantile table:

1. χ2(28)(0.025) = 15.31
2. χ2(28)(0.975) = 44.46

Calculate Confidence Intervals:

- σ² (non-survivors) = 15.07 mm2

Confidence interval = (n-1) * σ² / χ2

1. 0.975 CI = (28-1)*(15.07)/15.31 = 26.58
2. 0.05 CI = (28-1)*(15.07)/44.46 = 9.15

The variance for survivors (n=21) is 11.05 mm2

The variance of the length of survivors (i.e 11.05 mm2) is compatible with the confidence interval range for non-survivors (0.975 = 26.58, 0.025 = 9.15)  Therefore, from these calculations we are 95 % confident that the true population variance for survivors (n=21) does fall within the confidence intervals for non-survivors (n=28).

Comment: Question 1: I think you meant $(n-1)\sigma^2/\chi^2$ not $(n-1)\mu/\chi^2$. Also, check your degrees of freedom.

Comment: Thank you Blue-Footed Booby, an oversight. Much appreciated :) Otherwise is the methodology accurate?

Comment: Comparing the variance of length strikes me as unduly awkward way to go about this. Presumably these are some teacher's questions, but just plotting the data would be immensely more useful. Then you could check whether lengths are normal (instead of assuming that).

Comment: The 0.975 confidence limit (not interval) would usually be paired with the 0.025 limit (not the 0.05 limit). That pair of limits would then be the 0.95 or 95% confidence interval.

Comment: I started editing this but then got bored. I'll leave you to find instances where variance of length is stated to be in mm (mostly you got that right).

Comment: Thank you Nick Cox, I have amended the error for CI (0.025). Unfortunately we were not given the data, only the information provided. Your advice is much appreciated.

Comment: I doubt that it is intentional but this is an echo of mediocre statistical practice from say the 1950s....

Comment: I think this post is too broad.  Break up your questions into separate posts.  Then you will have a chance to get some answers instead of just comments.

Comment: It would be more likely for you to get useful answers if you split this up as @MichaelChernick suggested (a) someone may be able to help with only one part (b) it is rather forbidding at the moment and volunteer helpers are going to be put off reading through so much.

Comment: How did you arrive at your statement that $\sigma^2 = 3.882$? I think there is an error there.

Comment: I can now see my mistake, I was using the standard deviation (σ = 3.882) rather than the variance for non-survivors